# In Hakyll, how can I generate a tags page?

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I'm trying to do something like [what's described in this tutorial](https://javran.github.io/posts/2014-03-01-add-tags-to-your-hakyll-blog.html), i.e., add tags to my Hakyll blog, but instead of generating a page for every tag, just have one page that lists all tags and their posts. So given a `Post1` tagged `Tag1`, and a `Post2` tagged `Tag1, Tag2`, and a `Post3` tagged `Tag2`, my `tags.html` would look like this:

```
 Tag1: 
  - Post1
  - Post2
 Tag2: 
  - Post2
  - Post3
```

But I'm a Haskell beginner, and I don't fully understand all of Hakyll's monadic contexts. Here's what I have so far:

```
create ["tags.html"] $ do
    route idRoute
    tags <- buildTags "posts/*" (fromCapture "tags.html")
    compile $
        makeItem ""
            >>= applyTemplate tagListTemplate defaultContext
            >>= applyTemplate defaultTemplate defaultContext
            >>= relativizeUrls
            >>= cleanIndexUrls
```

The problem is, I don't really know what `Tags` are, in the context of my blog. I can't seem to print them out for debugging. (I tried adding `print tags`, but it doesn't work.) So I'm having a really hard time thinking about how to proceed with this.

[The complete file is here on GitHub.](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/jonreeve.com-hakyll/blob/eb6f3e44127dc5dc63f14febec935ea7e06af8c9/site.hs#L76)

Any help is much appreciated.

**Update**: I'm still not much closer to figuring this out. Here's what I'm trying now:

```
create ["tags.html"] $ do
        route idRoute
        tags <- buildTags "posts/*" (fromCapture "tags.html#")
        let tagList = tagsMap tags
        compile $ do
            makeItem ""
              >>= applyTemplate tagListTemplate (defaultCtxWithTags tags)
```

along with:

```
-- Add tags to default context, for tag listing
defaultCtxWithTags :: Tags -> Context String
defaultCtxWithTags tags = listField "tags" defaultContext (return (tagsMap tags)) `mappend` defaultContext
```

[The full code, as it currently stands, is up here.](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/jonreeve.com-hakyll/blob/master/site.hs#L127)

Any help with this would be much appreciated. I'm aware of all the documentation, but I can't seem to translate that into working code.

Comment: See [the documentation on what `Tags` are](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.12.4.0/docs/Hakyll-Web-Tags.html#t:Tags). You will need to use one of the functions that take a `Tags` argument and produce a `Compiler` or better `Context`, that you can use instead of (or together with) the `defaultContext`.

Comment: That documentation doesn't really make sense to me, as a beginner. What function should I use to take the `tags` that I generated, and make a context from it that contains a list of all tags, and all their associated posts?

Comment: It's a normal [algebraic `data` type](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses). You can use `tagsMap tags` to get a list of tuples, each with a tag name and a list of page identifiers having that tag. Then read the `Template` and [`Context` documentation](https://github.com/bergus/hakyll/blob/master/lib/Hakyll/Web/Template/Context.hs) for how to build a `listField` from that, which you should be able to use to render a list of tag names.

Comment: (Rendering the (titles etc of) associated posts themselves will be more advanced, since the tag list will only contain post identifiers. You won't easily get the metadata of that page to render it, that'll require additional effort).

Comment: What will that involve, exactly? Is there a function for getting the title of a page, given its identifier?

Comment: Yes, [`getMetadata`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.12.4.0/docs/Hakyll-Core-Metadata.html#v:getMetadata) will do that (when called in a `Compiler` monad or the top-level `Rule` monad). But first try to get the list of tag names working, and post an update to your question if you did.

Comment: I just posted an update. I'm getting closer, but I don't think I know how to make a `listField` from `tagsMap tags`.

Answer (score 13):

I have modified your `site.hs` to create a rudimentary tags list page which I believe has the structure required: a list of tags, each of which contains a list of posts with that tag.

Here's a summary of each of the things that I had to do to get it to work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
```

Not strictly necessary, but a nice language extension which I use once. I thought I'd use/mention it since you mentioned that you're a beginner to Haskell, and it's nice to know about.

```
tags <- buildTags "posts/*" (fromCapture "tags/*.html")
```

There are two changes needed to this line, compared to the `buildTags` in your initial `site.hs`. One is that it should probably moved out of the individual `match` clauses into the top level `Rules` monad, so that we can create individual tag pages if required. The other is that the capture was similarly changed from `"tags.html#"` to `"tags/*.html"`. This is important because Hakyll wants every `Item` to have a unique `Identifier`, and not every tags page is the same.

Having the individual tag pages with unique identifiers may not be strictly necessary, but simplifies the rest of the setup since a lot of the Hakyll machinery assumes they exist.  In particular, the `Tags:` line in the individual post descriptions was not previously being rendered correctly either.

For the same reason, it's a good idea to actually make these individual tag pages routable: without this stanza in the top-level `Rules` monad, the tags on each post won't render correctly with the default `tagsField` that you use, since they can't figure out how to link to an individual tag page:

```
tagsRules tags $ \tag pat -> do
    route idRoute
    compile $ do
        posts <- recentFirst =<< loadAll pat
        let postCtx = postCtxWithTags tags
            postsField = listField "posts" postCtx (pure posts)
            titleField = constField "title" ("Posts tagged \""++tag++"\"")
            indexCtx = postsField <> titleField <> defaultContext
        makeItem "" >>= applyTemplate postListTemplate indexCtx
                    >>= applyTemplate defaultTemplate defaultContext
                    >>= relativizeUrls
                    >>= cleanIndexUrls
```

Alright, that's the preliminaries. Now onto the main attraction:

```
defaultCtxWithTags tags = listField "tags" tagsCtx getAllTags         `mappend`
                          defaultContext
```

Alright, the important thing added here is some `tags` field. It will contain one item for each thing returned by `getAllTags`, and the fields on each item will be given by `tagsCtx`.

```
  where getAllTags :: Compiler [Item (String, [Identifier])]
        getAllTags = pure . map mkItem $ tagsMap tags
          where mkItem :: (String, [Identifier]) -> Item (String, [Identifier])
                mkItem x@(t, _) = Item (tagsMakeId tags t) x
```

What's `getAllTags` doing? Well, it starts with `tagsMap tags`, just like your example. But Hakyll wants the result to be an `Item`, so we have to wrap it up using `mkItem`. What's in an `Item` other than the body? Just an `Identifier`, and the `Tags` object happens to contain a field that tells us how to get this! So `mkItem` just uses `tagsMakeId` to get an identifier and wraps up the given body with that identifier.

What about `tagsCtx?`

```
        tagsCtx :: Context (String, [Identifier])
        tagsCtx = listFieldWith "posts" postsCtx getPosts             `mappend`
                  metadataField                                       `mappend`
                  urlField "url"                                      `mappend`
                  pathField "path"                                    `mappend`
                  titleField "title"                                  `mappend`
                  missingField
```

Everything starting with `metadataField` is just the usual stuff we expect to get from `defaultContext`; we can't use `defaultContext` here since it wants to add a `bodyField`, but the body of this `Item` isn't a string (but instead a much more useful for us Haskell structure representing a tag).  The interesting bit of this is line which adds the `posts` field, which should look a bit familiar. The big difference is that it uses `listFieldWith` instead of `listField`, which basically means that `getPosts` gets an extra argument, which is the body of the `Item` that this field is on. In this case, that's the tag record from `tagsMap`.

```
          where getPosts :: Item (String, [Identifier])
                         -> Compiler [Item String]
                getPosts (itemBody -> (_, is)) = mapM load is
```

`getPosts` mostly just uses the `load` function to get ahold of the `Item` for each post given its `Identifier`---it's a lot like the `loadAll` you do to get all the posts on the index page, but it just gives you one post. The weird-looking pattern-match on the left is `ViewPatterns` in action: it's basically saying that for this pattern to match, the pattern on the right of the `->` (i.e. `(_, is)`) should match the result of applying the function on the left (i.e. `itemBody`) to the argument.

```
                postsCtx :: Context String
                postsCtx = postCtxWithTags tags
```

`postsCtx` is very simple: just the same `postCtxWithTags` used everywhere else we render a post.

That's everything necessary to get a `Context` with everything that you want; all that's left is to actually make a template to render it!

```
tagListTemplateRaw :: Html
tagListTemplateRaw =
  ul $ do
    "$for(tags)$"
    li ! A.class_ "" $ do
      a ! href "$url$" $ "$title$"
      ul $ do
        "$for(posts)$"
        li ! A.class_ "" $ do
          a ! href "$url$" $ "$title$"
        "$endfor$"
    "$endfor$"
```

This is just a very simple template that renders nested lists; you could of course do various things to make it fancier/nicer-looking.

I have made a PR to your repo so that you can see these changes in context [here](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/jonreeve.com-hakyll/pull/1).

Comment: Thanks so much for this very thorough answer! Besides being helpful for me, I think it'll go a long way toward helping others that are also looking to do this in Hakyll, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what we've done to achieve this behaviour on our webpage:

[Kowainik webpage tags building](https://github.com/kowainik/kowainik.github.io/blob/e3976e9eb686f6511258b3cea487af59f7c64bd6/site.hs#L61-L66)

And the example of the tag page:

https://kowainik.github.io/tags/haskell

You can ask any questions about the code :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it looks like your website has one page for each tag. I can achieve that just fine, but what I'm having trouble with is making one page that lists all tags, and for each tag lists all its associated posts.

Comment: @Jono We actually have a page that lists all tags (this is all posts page), but without showing associated posts with that. But probably the trick with grabbing all tags from all posts could be useful for you if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: I can manage to print out a list of all tags, and I can make tag pages which each list all the associated posts for that tag, but I can't make a page that lists tags along with their associated posts. I have a feeling it involves creating a `tagsListContext`, a `listField` of tags, and `listField`s inside each of those. But I don't understand how a `field` is necessarily associated with an `Item`, and how they interact. I just wish I could find a working example of a tags page that lists all tags, and for each one, lists all the associated posts.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include a working code block that lists tags, then within each, lists their associated posts? It would be something that begins `create ["tags.html"] $ do`, I'm guessing. If so, I'd happily give you the bounty.